# Storing and searching data pairs in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to figure out how to store and search data pairs. I have a document similar to that below and my goal is to perform a search that returns all documents with a given specialty and then sort the results by the matching specialty ability:

```
<doc>
    <id>123</id>
    <firstName>Joe</firstName>
    <lastName>Bloggs</lastName>
    <specialties>
        <specialty>
            <type>Foo</type>
            <ability>1</ability>
        </specialty>
        <specialty>
            <type>Bar</type>
            <ability>2</ability>
        </specialty>
        <specialty>
            <type>Baz</type>
            <ability>2</ability>
        </specialty>
    </specialties>
</doc>
```

I'm familiar with working indexing, searching and faceting simple documents but I am struggling to even find a starting point with this =(

Should I simply use two collections and join?

Comment: How would you compare two users if they had abilities like `Joe={1, 2, 2}` and `Bob = {2, 2, 1}`?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of specialties is finite and known beforehand, you may try following.

Instead of having two fields storing specialty and ability, just have ONE field containing **"ability_of_a_specialty"**

For example,

```
<specialties>
    <Foo_ability> 1 </Foo_ability>
    <Bar_ability> 2 </Bar_ability>
    <Dummy_ability> 0 </Dummy_ability>
    ...
</specialties>
```

Now, it should be straightforward to transform the above attributes to a Lucene doc.